# function still working after global variable change

Tags: jquery, html

Ok I have the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(selected == 0){
    $(".color").mouseover(function(){
        var image = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        $(this).children('img').css("border", "2px solid #000000");
        $("#itemMainImg").attr("src", image);
    });
    $(".color").mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children('img').css("border", "none");
    })
    $(".color").click(function(){
        var image = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        console.log("worked");
        $("#itemMainImg").attr("src", image);
        $(this).children('img').css("border", "2px solid #000000");
        selected = 1;
        console.log(selected);
        colorSelected = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
    });
}
else{
    $(".color").click(function(){
        var image = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        if(image == colorSelected){
            $("#itemMainImg").attr("src", image);
            if($(this).children('img').css("border") == "none"){
                $(this).children('img').css("border","2px solid #000000");
            }
            else{
                $(this).children('img').css("border", "none");
                selected = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}   
});
```

I have a global variable assigned var selected = 0;

and var colorSelected = "";

The html looks like this:

```
<div id="itemHead">
<div id="itemMain">
    <h1 id="itemH1">Demo Item by Demo</h1>
    <img id="itemMainImg" src="photos/Carpets/ApolloBoxwood - Copy.jpg">
</div>
<div id="itemColors">
    <div>
        <p id="colorsP">Available Colours</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="color">
            <img class="colorImg" src="photos/Carpets/ApolloBoxwood - Copy.JPG" alt="Apollo Plus Boxwood">
            <p class="colorPara">Boxwood</p>
        </div>
        <div class="color">
            <img class="colorImg" src="photos/Carpets/ApolloCinderGrey - Copy.JPG" alt="Apollo Plus Cinder Grey">
            <p class="colorPara">Cinder Grey</p>
        </div>
        <div class="color">
            <img class="colorImg" src="photos/Carpets/ApolloCorkOak - Copy.JPG" alt="Apollo Plus Cork Oak">
            <p class="colorPara">Cork oak</p>
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

for some reason when I click on the .color divs the selected value is changed to 1, but the function still acts like the value is 0. So on page var selected gets set to 1, but the first part of the if statement still works. I don't think it should as I've changed the global variable with the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your click events on document ready based on the value of `selected` - only the first click event in your code will ever be bound to the element as the initial value is zero. You need to move the logic in to the click function so that the value is checked every time the function runs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".color").click(function(){
       if(selected == 0){
          /* do something if value is zero */
       } else {
          /* do something if value is NOT zero */
       }
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks, theres still a bit of tweaking but it worked.